# Exercise bikes and the computer

Tags: windows, macos, user-interface

Are there any kits or products available for an exercise bike to connect to a PC so that you can get speed, calories, etc. tracked on a small application running in a PC (or Mac)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly all of the **much** more expensive exercise bikes have the ability to do this, or something similar.

I have seen everything from stores a file on a USB stick so that you can connect it to a pc and load in a special application, down to ones that save to a web based portal

For example - [Life Fitness - 95R](http://www.fitness-superstore.co.uk/recumbent_exercise_bikes/life_fitness_95r_elevation_series_recumbent_lifecycle_engage_console/10561_p.html) (£6495)

> Workout Tracking - Utilize the USB connectivity to create, plan and track workouts for free at the Life Fitness Virtual Trainer web site.

However, there are many many different manufacturers and I have no idea what is even available to you where you are... For something like this, you should really go to a specialist store (negotiate with prices you find online) and get help from someone experienced.

Comment: "You Save £8.25" ... now HOW cool is that? :D

Comment: ahahaha! I think is something like 6495 times cooler than my bike!

Comment: Ouch! I was looking for something simple that could...I don't know, take data from sensors on a flywheel and/or resistance and use it to graph information in a small real-time application  while viewing a video or web browsing, not necessarily reading to a web site or a fullscreen "virtual biking tour". Something more like redirecting what is normally on the bike's LCD/LED panel to a computer readout. Probably sounds like a homebrew thing instead :-(